# Why do file geodatabase and SDE readers produce different fme_geometry types?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, geometry, file-geodatabase, fme-form

I have one very simple workbench that I am running against both SDE (9.3) and FGDB (10.0) sources.

I noticed two different fme_geometry values for same type of objects.

For the first one, i.e SDE 9.3, I have `fme_geometry=fme_donut`, but for the same features in FGDB 10.0 I have `fme_geometry=fme_aggregate`.

Is this a "problem" of converting ESRI data from 9.3 to 10.0 or how FME interprets geometry?

Because in case of fme_aggregate, FME is doing "additional" job of constructing donuts again:

```
Calculating inside points
Determining uppermost containment
Constructing donuts from xxx points
```

(Visible in log window)

Comment: An fme_aggregate is equivalent to a multi-part polygon. Are you sure that the features you are comparing are actually the same in this respect (it would seem that one is multi-part and the other is not).

Comment: Also I'm sure I've mentioned this before, but you will probably get more focused answers on the [FME Community Answers](http://fmepedia.safe.com/answerssearch) site than here.

Comment: ok, you have right blah238!

Comment: Anyone here? I asked this question FME Community also.

Comment: FME can transform your information from SDE to FGDB for compatibility. Example: I think the scale or the tolerance of ArcSDE are not the same in FGDB.

Comment: I suppose a question back should be, why do you think that FME should produce the same geometry types?